# Generate all possible combinations of classifiers in weka

Tags: java, classification, weka

I am working on classification and using WEKA for it. I have currently 9 classifiers but I want to pick five out of them, in order to implement majority voting. But I dont know which five classifiers will give me best result and hence I want to run my program for all the possible combination of five classifiers. Can any one please suggest how should I go about it.  Following is part of my WEKA code:

```
     Classifier[] cfsArray = new Classifier[5];  
     Logistic       cfs1 = new Logistic();
     BayesNet       cfs2 = new BayesNet();                      
     ADTree         cfs3 = new ADTree();
     DecisionTable  cfs4 = new DecisionTable();
     AdaBoostM1     cfs5 = new AdaBoostM1();
     J48            cfs6 = new J48();  
     RandomForest   cfs7 = new RandomForest();
     NaiveBayes     cfs8 = new NaiveBayes();
     RBFNetwork     cf9  = new RBFNetwork();

      cfsArray[0]=cfs1;
      cfsArray[1]=cfs2;
      cfsArray[2]=cfs3;
      cfsArray[3]=cfs4;
      cfsArray[4]=cfs5;

      //cfsArray[5]=cfs5;
     // cfsArray[6]=cfs7;
      //cfsArray[7]=cfs8;

      Vote voter =  new Vote();  
      voter.setClassifiers(cfsArray); 
      voter.setCombinationRule(new SelectedTag(Vote.MAJORITY_VOTING_RULE, Vote.TAGS_RULES));
```